# How to compare two dataframe columns to see if value in one column is in object of other column

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I want to compare two different columns in a dataframe (called station_programming_df).  I have one dataframe column that contains integers (called 'facility_id').  I have a second dataframe column that contains a dataframe object (which contains a series of integers)(called 'parsed_final_participant_val') .  I want to see if the integer in the first column is in the column with the dataframe object (the second column).  If true, I want to return a "1" in a new column (i.e., 'master_color')

I have tried various approaches including using python's "isin" function, which is not returning errors but is also not returning the correct amount.  I have also attempted to convert the datatypes as well but with no luck.

```
station_programming_df['master_color']=np.where(station_programming_df['facility_id'].isin(station_programming_df['final_participants_val']),1,0 )
```

Here is what the dataframe that I am using looks like:

DATA:

```
facility_id,final_participants_val,master_color
35862,"62469,33894,33749,34847,21656,35396,4624,69571",0
35396,"62469,33894,33749,34847,21656,35396,4624,69571",0
```

While no error message is returned, I am not finding any matches. The second row should have returned a "1" in the master_color column.

I am wondering if it has to do with how it is interpreting the series (final_participants_val)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.apply` and `in`.

```
station_programming_df['master_color'] = station_programming_df.apply(lambda x: str(x.facility_id) in x.final_participants_val, axis=1)
```

```
  facility_id                          final_participants_val  master_color
0        35862  62469,33894,33749,34847,21656,35396,4624,69571         False
1        35396  62469,33894,33749,34847,21656,35396,4624,69571          True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
station_programming_df['master_color']=station_programming_df.apply(lambda x:  1 if str(x['facility_id']) in x['final_participants_val'] else 0,axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
   facility_id                          final_participants_val  master_color
0        35862  62469,33894,33749,34847,21656,35396,4624,69571             0
1        35396  62469,33894,33749,34847,21656,35396,4624,69571             1
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was what I was missing!